# PWM with Unipolar Voltage Switching in Single Phase Full Bridge-Odd vs Even frequency modulation ratio mf

Tags: pwm, inverter, harmonics, single-phase, full-bridge

I simulate a Single Phase Full Bridge Inverter in Matlab/Simulink and PSIM and the control method that I use is PWM with Unipolar Voltage Switching. In the book "Power Electronics Handbook", Rashid, and  other references(Power Electronics, Mohan), it is recommended that:

"if mf is taken even, the harmonics in the ac output voltage appear at normalized odd frequencies fh centered around twice the normalized carrier frequency mf and its multiples. Specifically,

h=l(mf+k) or h=l(mf-k) for l=2,4,...  eq. (1)"

However, when I run the simulation in Matlab/Simulink or PSIM either if I choose even or odd mf the eq. (1) is valid. I tested the system with various mf values either low (mf = 8, 9, 19), medium (mf= 21,22,23) or high (mf=149,150,151,152) and the eq. (1) was true for all.

Also, in conference paper "Testing and Hardware Implementation of SPWM Inverter using TMSF28335eZDSP" by Surabhi Chandra,et al and master thesis "Evaluation and DSP Based Implementation of PWM Approaches for Single-Phase DCAC Converters" by Lining Zhou (Florida State University), it is recommended to use even mf in order to reach odd and half-wave
symmetry.

Thus, I would like to ask:

1. Is it true that in order to reach odd and half-wave symmetry, mf should be even?
2. Why it is recommended to use even mf if the eq. (1) is true for both even and odd mf and the THD % is almost the same?

[image]

mf = 11 (f1=50Hz)
[image]

mf=10 (f1=50Hz)
[image]

Comment: Please post an image of the section you are trying to quote please. Also post images of your schematic.